# Help with demonstrating the meaning of this information

Tags: logic-gates

Regarding the following information about open drain and push pull configurations:

> The advantage of the push-pull output is the higher speed, because the
> line is driven both ways. With the pull up the line can only rise as
> fast as the RC time constant allows. The R is the pull up, the C is
> the parasitic capacitance, including the pin capacitance and the board
> capacitance.
>
> The push-pull can typically source more current. With the open-drain the current is limited by the R and R cannot be made very
> small, because the lower transistor has to sink that current when the
> output is low; that means higher power consumption.
>
> However, the open-drain allows you to short several outputs together, with a common pull up. This is called an wired-OR
> connection. Now you can drive the output low with any of the IO pins.
> To drive it high all outputs have to be high. This is advantageous in
> some situations, because it eliminates the external gates that would
> otherwise be required.

I'm stuck with understanding two parts above:

1-) "With the open-drain the current is limited by the R and R cannot be made very small" What is meant by that?

2-) Regarding  wired-OR: "This is advantageous in some situations, because it eliminates the external gates that would otherwise be required." Why would external gates required in push-pull case

Can these be explained by using circuit diagrams?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The early logic, from Fairchild, was RTL resistor-transistor-logic.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmE1r6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Why R cannot be made very small in open drain config?

Comment: Because of excessive power consumption in both the transistor and the resistor. That would overheat the chip.